# Best way to store locations data

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best way to store locations data in the database?

Separate tables for country, state, city with foreign key relations.

Or a single table with everything.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you want to make use of the data.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have to list people and business in my app. Users will be able to search other people on app in any city/state or country and the same for business. Which one do you suggest for a fresher like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a DimGeography table with Country, State, City information. You can have GeographyID as Foreign key.

This Geography dimension you can extrapolate with Region, Area information also. Eg. North America, APAC can be Areas.

Generally, though citynames can repeat across states/countries, it is rare and it will lead to confusion, if you are manintaining them as separate tables and storing them in your main table. You have to make sure that you are picking up the right city from right state in right country. You have to follow the order from top to bottom. Otherwise, you might be mapping to wrong city in wrong state in wrong country.

In future, if you go for reporting scenarios also, this will be easier to define hierarchies and doing aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

it is all depending on your problem, the context used  and the data you want to manipulate
but generally, in terms of the database, they are separate because a country contains more than a state and the state is represented by a (state code, name, number of people, location,  ...) and it is the same for cities in the same state.

But in terms of class (OOP), it may be gathered in the same class